# Upgrade to 3.5.17

Tags: upgrade

All went well during the upgrade process, and I can access my Control Panel no problem. I had disabled all Addons prior to the upgrade. Now when I go to my home page, it is blank. After enabling Debug, I get this:

Exception Caught
Dependency Injection: Unregistered service "ee:Variables/Parser"
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Dependency/InjectionContainer.php:184

Prior version was 2.5.5

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not tried this already, move all the files / folders in the system/user/addons directory somewhere else and try opening your control panel.  Removing the files from the addons directory prevents EE from loading these addons, and so while you may get some errors arising because it cannot find the addons it is looking for, you eliminate errors caused by incompatibilities in the add-ons found in that folder.

EE changed how addons work between EE2 and EE3, so EE2 addons will not work in EE3.  Unfortunately, although EE could easily test for EE3 compatibility and not load those that are not compatible, it doesn't do this and attempts to load anything it finds in that directory: if there are issues of compatibility you find out via opaque errors instead.  That seems to be what is happening in your current circumstance.

If you can get the EE CP to load with no add-ons in the addons folder, then start adding them back one at a time and see how you go - if you add one back and EE crashes, you know that there is an issue with that add-on and you'll have to fix it or work around it.

If you post a list of whatever addons you have in the addons folder under EE2, it will be possible to reply with whether or not there are EE3 compatible versions and so on.

HTH

Comment: (You look familiar. Are you following me? LOL)

I managed to get to version 2.11.9 now with minimal tears and swearing. Are there template elements that version 3.x will not like? I recall seeing notes or posts about having to edit templates, or incompatible code, or something. It would be very handy to have a detailed list of what needs to be removed or changed when upgrading to 3.x 

These are my Modules and Plugins, only two are third party

Need to do another comment ..

Comment: Modules
Blacklist/Whitelist 3.0.1

Channel 2.0.1

Comment 2.3.2

Email 1.1

Emoticon 1

File --

IP to Nation --

jQuery --

Mailing List 3.2

Member 2.1

Metaweblog API 2.2
Moblog 3.2
Pages 2.2
Query 1
Referrer 2.1.1
Rich Text Editor 1.0.1
RSS 1
Search 2.2.2
Simple Commerce --
Statistics 2
Wiki 2.3


Plugins
  
Edit Comments 1.1 Third Party

Magpie RSS Parser 1.3.5 

Markdown 1 

RSS Parser 1 

XML Encode 1.3 

Safecracker File 2.1 Third Party

Comment: The only ones you need to worry about are the third-party ones; all the Ellis Labs ones either exist in newer versions or migrate to functions that do same thing.  So just focus on whatever is in your 'thirdparty' folder - you will need to change these for EE3 compatible versions if they exist to do the upgrade.  If you give a list of the folders in your thirdparty folder should be able to give guidance on next steps.  HTH

Comment: OK, the only things in third party are edit_comments and safecracker_file

Comment: Safecracker File can be replaced by the built-in file field.  I am not familar with edit_comments, but it appears to be an AJAX / Javascript overlay for editing comments - so probably not a big deal to leave out during migration.  So I would move both of those add-on directories to some other location and try running the update to EE3 again.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY! I have upgraded all the way to 5.2.4. I took it step by step, backing up each successful install, along with the database, as I went. Going from EE3 to EE4 was the trickiest - for some reason, the members table was missing several columns. Were I not fluent in SQL, that would have been quite difficult to overcome, because I had to manually insert the columns. EE4 to EE5 had only one snag - I needed to update PHP to 5.6.

Now I get to re-learn EE all over again, plus the Multi Site Manager, which isn't playing nice yet.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Congratulations!  If your ISP / host can support it, I would strongly encourage you updating to php7.1 or 7.2 - it is soooo much faster than php 5 :)